# Ifequal in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Models.py

```
solution_req = models.CharField(max_length=250, default=0, choices=(('FLC', 'FLC'), ('FSC', 'FSC'),
                                                                        ('Crate', 'Crate'), ('PPBox', 'PP Box')))
```

HTML

```
                {% ifequal l.solution_req PPBox %}

                <a href="{% url 'emp:ppbox_form' l.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Solution</a>

                {% else %}

                <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
                    Create Solution
                </button>
                {% endifequal %}
```

The above are my models and django templates

The problem is when the object has `solution_req` as PPBox it is still showing the disabled button instead of the link

Comment: may it help: `{% if l.solution_req == "PPBox" %} ... {% endif %}`

Comment: @ehsanahmadi It sure did, but I also need to know why ifequal was not working, can you please explain ?

Comment: wrap PPBox in quotation marks: `{% ifequal l.solution_req "PPBox" %}`